# quiero imprimir un arreglo bidimensional en c# con puros 0

Tags: c#, array

quiero imprimir el arreglo con puros 0 cuando pongo writeline(0); lo hace pero cuando quiero usar el arreglo no los imprime, no marca error solo no los imprime. No se cual es el problema

```
public class MapCell
{
   public int id;
    public  MapCell()
    {
         id = 0;
    }

    
}
 class GameMap
{
   

        MapCell[,] cells = new MapCell[15, 10];

    public void Draw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(cells[i,j].id);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del segundo **ciclo for** debes poner:

```
var map = new MapCell();
```

De esta forma construyes el objeto de tipo **MapCell** inicializandose por defecto su campo id a **0** como indicas en el constructor:

Entonces después pondrías:

```
cells[i, j] = map;
```

Podrías imprimir de la siguiente forma:

```
Console.Write(cells[i, j].id);
```

O de esta forma:

```
Console.Write(map.id);
```

O directamente imprimir:

```
Console.Write(0);
```

Lo que tú haces es declarar un arreglo bidimensional de **15** x **10** donde cada celda es un objeto de tipo **MapCell**. No te imprimía nada porque en las celdas no tenías ningún objeto, era null.